# running java class from shell script

Tags: java, shell, classpath

I have a problem changing a windows batch file into a unix shell script to execute the same java code on my linux machine.

My shell script looks like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

libdir=../lib
bindir=.
LIBS=$libdir/lib_1.jar;$libdir/lib_2.jar;$libdir/lib_3.jar;$libdir/lib_4.jar

java -cp $bindir;$LIBS com.sample.SampleServer
```

For me it looks correct but I am getting the following error message:
`Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from /home/user/development/lib/lib_2.jar`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parts of the classpath need to be separated by colons (:) on UNIX, not by semicolon (both in -cp and in LIBS).